# Elasticsearch logging an object without logging object type

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have an object:

```
var people = new List<Person> {
new Person { Name = "John Doe", Age = 30 },
new Person { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 25 } };
```

logger.LogInformation("{@people }", people);

the serilog/elasticsearch logging creates the following log:

```
[Person { Name: "John Doe", Age: 30 }, Person { Name: "Jane Doe", Age: 25 }]
```

but I need the following:

```
[{"Name":"John Doe","Age":30},{"Name":"Jane Doe","Age":25}]
```

what should I do to remove logging entity type?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous object to do that:

```
people.Select(x => new {Name = x.Name, Age = x.Age})
```

You will need to serialize this list after selecting the objects.

Comment: I don't want to create anonymous object (with many properties) just for logging.

Comment: You could also write a method that will take a generic object and create an anonymous object using reflection.